# jquery content slider jump back to top after click on hyper link

Tags: jquery, slider

I am completely new to jquery and dont know anything but I am developing my 3d tutorial website and using simple jquery content slider. Everything is fine only when I click on hyper link it jump back to top of the page. I have tried out to search here in database but I couldnt found appropriate to my need.

I have created content slider with this tutorial and use exact code http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/01/12/lightest-jquery-content-slider-ever-made-380-bytes/

Please guide me how to solve this.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to prevent default behaviour of links:

Modify these lines, passing "event" to the function and then preventing default on it:

```
$('#button a').click(function(event){ // added "event"
  event.preventDefault(); // this is a new line just inside function
  // rest of the script as before
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much... solve the issue and works like charm.. I have one more issue with this.. I want to use same slider in 3 different are at the same place and style also the same. So how to get three slider on the same page?

Comment: Can anyone help me to make this slider auto slid or fades in and out?

Answer (score 0):

your demo contains

```
href="#"
```

the # sign is assigned to the top of the page.

you should put your own labels like these in your doc

and then yo navigate by

```
#myCarDiv

#myGuitarDiv
```

Comment: "His" demo is the original author's demo. And the JS doesn't actually use those values to navigate, though I think this will actually help simply because the href will then be invalid and therefore not invoked. :-)

Comment: Can you please help me to make this slider auto rotate?